# what is the reason showing #N/A after write.xlsx in R?

Tags: r

I wrote the write.xlsx command from the xlsx package when I open the excel, it shows N/A in cells. what can I do, doesn't show #N/A [image]

```
Data1 <- structure(list(PM10 = c("13-", "19", "25", "17", NA, "22"), Hourly_Average = c(NA_real_,  NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_)), row.names = c(NA,  6L), class = "data.frame")

write.xlsx(Data1, file = "PM10 Valid Stations.xlsx")
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you put `dput(head(Data1))` in the console and paste the results in your post?

Comment: What package are you using to get the `write.xlsx()` function? Sometimes there is an àrgument like `write.csv(..., na = "NA", ...)` that you can change to `na = "#N/A"` for example so you get `#N/A` in your final file.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [write.xlsx in R giving incorrect NA in cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40125821/write-xlsx-in-r-giving-incorrect-na-in-cell)

Comment: `r 
  dput(head(Data1))
structure(list(PM10 = c("13-", "19", "25", "17", NA, "22"), Hourly_Average = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_)), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")` @sindri_baldur

Comment: That's how Excel indicates a missing or invalid value. What exactly were you expecting to get instead?

Comment: @Paul
Package: xlsx
Type: Package
Version: 0.6.0
Date: 2015-11-29
License: GPL-3

Comment: I expected that gives me the average value in excel. @camille

Comment: I run these codes
`r  PM10_Validation<- function() {
  Data = read.xlsx("pirozi95.xlsx", sheetIndex = "PM10", colIndex = 1, startRow = 1, endRow = 8785)
  Data[Data <=0] <- NA 
  Data1 = Data[colMeans(is.na(Data))<0.25]
  Data1$Hourly_Average<-apply(Data1,1,mean,na.rm=TRUE)
  Hourly<-data.frame(Data1$Hourly_Average)
  Daily<-colMeans(matrix(Hourly[,1],nrow=24), na.rm=T)
  Daily<-data.frame(Daily)
  colnames(Daily)<-"Daily_Averages"
  write.xlsx(Data1, file = "PM10 Valid Stations.xlsx")
}`

Comment: Within the snippet of data you posted, that column is only `NA`. Excel will denote that as `#N/A`. You should check that the data you're writing out *definitely* has values that aren't `NA`

Answer (score 0):

I don't use `xlsx` package a lot but it seems there is a `showNA` argument in `write.xlsx()`

You can try:

```
write.xlsx(Data1, file = "PM10 Valid Stations.xlsx", showNA = FALSE)
```

I usually prefer using `writexl`or `openxlsx` packages:

```
writexl::write_xlsx(Data1, path = "PM10 Valid Stations.xlsx")
openxlsx::write.xlsx(Data1, file = "PM10 Valid Stations.xlsx")
```

Comment: I wrote `showNA` and it could remove #N/A but I want to be valued in cells.  may my cod be wrong? @jmpivette

Comment: Not sure I understand what you are trying to do. What value do you want to be displayed in your xlsx file?
Can you maybe share an example of the expected output?

Comment: I want to give it to me hourly average of PM10 concentration in output but I don't know why it is #N/A instead of  hourly average value in excel

Comment: It looks like your problem is not in the xlsx file but inside your data.frame `Data1`. There are no values in Hourly_Average only `NA`